# What does a query return in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

When we execute an "Alter" query in SQL Server, we get "command executed successfully" message.

So my question is, what makes SQL Server show that message after execution of the query?

As far as in know, that query may return some value, depending on that value, SQL Server decides which message to show. So, what is that value that gets returned based on which SQL Server shows that successful message?

Answer (score 1):

The messages tab shows what `SqlConnection.InfoMessage` returns. This is a TDS protocol feature. SQL Server cannot just return result sets, it also can return messages and errors.

SSMS did not decide what to show. It just outputs whatever SQL Server sends to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is handled at `TDS` layer,depending on statements ,Client may return one of the token values..

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd341450.aspx) contains all TOKENS

For Example..

> Token Stream Name:DONE

Indicates the completion status of a SQL statement.

> This token is used to indicate the completion of a SQL statement. As multiple SQL statements can be sent to the server in a single SQL batch, multiple DONE tokens can be generated. In this case, all but the final DONE token will have a Status value with DONE_MORE bit set .

Also check this link on  to know [how SQLServer executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT customerstable =  CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Company, Address, City, State, Country, PostalCode, Phone, Fax, Email, SupportRepId.

FROM: customers  Germany;

RETURN LastName, Country columns

Comment: This answer is not related to the question.
Naresh was asking about "What the MSSQL SERVER returns when it executes a query". 
You can take a look at the other answers to understand it better.